# Maven WAR overlay problems, while using Hudson + Artifactory

Tags: maven, hudson, war

We have three artifacts:

```
common.jar   : with common classes.
public.war   : depending on the common.jar, contains only public site resources.
internal.war : depends on both common.jar and public.war, adding authentication
               information and security context resource files. Also contains
               few administration site classes.
```

Currently I have structured these in such way, that internal.war [overlays](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html) itself with public.war.

Building the project locally, installing the artifacts to local repo, works perfectly.

Problems start when trying to get the Hudson builds working with following sequence:

1. Build all projects in dependency order.
2. Modify common.jar (say, add a new class method)
3. Modify internal.war classes in such way that they are compile-time dependent on changes done in 2. step.
4. Commit both changes, triggering the Hudson builds.
5. Internal.war build fails because it can not find the symbols added in step 2.

Somehow the build in step 5. is using an old version of the common.jar, and failing because of it.

The common.jar version number does not change, let's say it's 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT for the purposes of this example.

If I DO change the common.jar version number, the build works. (Supposedly because there is only one release by a release version number).

Now, what could cause this using of old artifacts in Hudson builds?

We are running maven builds on Hudson with command "clean package -e -X -U"

"Deploy artifacts to maven repository" has been checked.

Comment: Just to make sure, do you mean Jenkins or actually Hudson?

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to definitively answer this without access to the real poms, but here is what I would do:

1) Make sure Hudson is using the exact same version of Maven as you are on your local machine

2) Examine the effective pom.xml of internal.war on the Hudson machine in a terminal via `mvn  help:effective-pom` making sure you are running the same mvn executable as your Hudson job does.  You need to verify the version of the common.jar in the effective pom.xml of internal.war.  It could be different than what you expect due to profiles or settings.xml differences.

3) Check the settings.xml file for your Hudson install of Maven.  In particular you need to verify all is well in your distributionManagement, servers, and repositories stanzas.  Another good way to check this is to go to your internal.war project and run `mvn  help:effective-settings` and see if what is there matches what is on your local machine.

Something is awry and it won't take long to find with the right analysis.